# Java factory pattern, creating specific classes

Tags: java, factory

I had a question on an interview where I had 2 types of foods, say bread and cake, was given the following:

```
 public class FoodFactory{};

 public class Food{};

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Food foo = FoodFactory.get("bread");
    System.out.println(foo.getClass().getName());
 }
```

Given the `FoodFactory` class and `Food` class, I wasn't sure how to make this work so that it would print out `"bread"` for the class. It really seemed like the only way to have gotten it to print bread was to create a `Bread` class and have the `FoodFactory` return that.

I'm just wondering if I'm missing anything, because `FoodFactory` and `Food` were classes given so I assumed those were the only 2 classes I needed to change. Is there a way to have implemented the two classes given and made it print `"bread"` while using just those 2 classes?

Comment: Would be good to respect the Java syntax, especially for such a short snippet

Comment: *"I had 2 types of foods, say bread and cake"*--they should be two concrete classes extending `Food` I suppose. So the factory choose instance of which class to produce taking argument into account.

Comment: The short answer is no.  If there's no class called Bread, then `getClass().getName()` is never going to print "Bread".

Comment: @Dici yea sorry, I was just typing it up real quick my bad. Ok that makes sense. I kept trying to think about how this could be done with the classes given and didn't think it would allow me to make subclasses. Mistakes. Thanks again!

Comment: @Kevin the crazy solution may be to use bytecode library like javassist to create classes in runtime, but I think this is not what interviewer waits to hear.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou Javassist is great but would be overkill for just compiling a class. I remember it's fairly doable in plain old Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So one way to do it would be to make a class `Bread` which extends class `Food` and have the `FoodFactory.get()` return the appropriate object based on the string passed.

```
class Food {};

class Bread extends Food {};

class FoodFactory {
    public static Food get(String type){
        switch(type){
            case "bread" : return new Bread();
            default : return new Food();
        }     
    }
}
```

Another way to do it would be to use reflection.

Comment: This has 3 classes. But as the question mentions, there were only two classes

Answer (score 0):

Unless you compile a new class at runtime (which is possible, but inappropriate here), you will of course need to add a class if you want to return a `Bread` instance.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, `Food` should turn into an interface or an abstract class at best. Then you have classes `Bread` and `Cake` implement/extend `Food`. Your `FoodFactory` has a static method `get` that accepts the food as a String. Depending on the value, you instantiate and return one of the concrete classes which will give you what you need when you print class name.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the real question the interviewer was asking was if you understand the pattern and polymorphism. As noted in one of the comments `getClass().getName()` won't return 'Bread' unless there really is a Bread class. What you could have done was to the suggest the interviewer that `Food` is the base class which in this case should be extended by `Cake` and `Bread` classes, or even propose to change it to abstract class or interface. Then you could have proposed a simple factory class which would create the required implementation 'hidden' behind the base class interface.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is basically an example for the [Java Factory Design Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).
Assumed you have a project, respectively a class hierarchy with multiple Interfaces and different classes, what would be the easiest way to create any class? This is where a Factory comes in place to handle all operations regarding class instance creation.

Now to your case, the convenient way would be to change your `Class Food` to an interface eg:

```
public interface Food {
    String getType();
}
```

Now you need your `Cake` and `Bread` classes, which implement the `interface Food`

```
public class Cake implements Food{
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "Cake";
    }
}

public class Bread implements Food{
    @Override
    public String getType() {
        return "Bread";
    }
}
```

Now you need to define your `FoodFactory` class which has a static `get`method, that returns a `Food` depending on the criteria that has been supplied.

```
public class FoodFactory {
    public static Food get(String classifier){
        if(classifier.equals("Cake")) return new Cake();
        if(classifier.equals("Bread")) return new Bread();
    //no matching Food to create    
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The " + classifier + " is not a valid classifier");
    }
}
```

Once you have your Factory you can use it for any creation operation.
If you want to print out `Bread` from a Food instance, you can achieve this like this:

```
//food is now an instanceof Bread
Food food = FoodFactory.get("Bread");
System.out.println(food.getType());
```

Which simply just prints

`Bread`

Further:
To make sure every creation is handled only by the `FoodFactory` you should make every constructor of your Food classes `protected`